# Save data into dropbox/google docs without knowing user's password

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api

My users store some data on my website that they might like to backup on another site, for example dropbox or google docs.

Is there a way for me to save their data into their accounts but (here it comes...) without knowing their password? Like Paypal, where only Paypal sees your password, except more complicated because the user needs to ok that data be copied into their account?

Or does anyone have any clever ideas about this? They could, of course, just copy it to their desktop and drag it in from there. But maybe a nice way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just use the Saver: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver

No auth required. The user just logs in (if not already) and chooses a location, and the file gets saved into their Dropbox.

Comment: There is Google Drive equivalent feature, Save to Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

That is basically what OAuth2 does.
User accesses Google Drive/Dropbox website and log in to grant you access.
Then, you will get special access code which you can use to save data without you knowing user's password.

Here are some links you might find useful:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api